# How to reinsert all old rows into SQL Server table when month changes

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with `id`, `sname`, `attendance` columns like

```
id  sname attendance month
1    xyz     p         12  
2    asd     p         12  
3    qwe     L         12 
4    tyy     A         12
```

I want to reinsert `id` and `sname` for next month's `attendance` for every month.

Now I want to reinsert data for month 1 with AB in `Attendance` column like this:

```
id  sname attendance  month 
 1    xyz     p         12  
 2    asd     p         12  
 3    qwe     L         12 
 4    tyy     A         12 
 1    xyz     ab         1  
 2    asd     ab         1  
 3    qwe     ab         1
 4    tyy     ab         1
```

Comment: Where are months in the table?

Comment: sorry for that last field is for month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've got it right:

```
INSERT INTO t (id,sname,attendance,month)
SELECT id,sname,'ab',(month%12)+1 from t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO your_table (id,sname,attendance,month)
SELECT T.id, T.sname, T.attendance, M.m
FROM (SELECT 1 m UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) AS M
CROSS JOIN your_table T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE m=M.m)
```

And better don't use reserved words like `MONTH` for names of tables, columns and other objects.